# Convert ByteArray into Image in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, image, spring-boot

I have written a controller in spring boot for getting image of particular user and i am returning it in form of byte array

```
@GetMapping(value = "/images/{id}/{login}",produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE})
    public byte[] getImage(@Valid @RequestParam("id") String id,@RequestParam("login") String login)
        throws IOException, XmlPullParserException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidArgumentException, ErrorResponseException, NoResponseException, InvalidBucketNameException, InsufficientDataException, InternalException {
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(fileService.getImage(id, login));
    }
```

Is there a method in angularjs so that i could convert it in form of image
So that i could display the profile Picture of User

Comment: There's nothing to convert. What you should do, though, is specify the actual content type of the image: image/png, or image/jpeg for example, but certainy not application/octet-stream. All you need is `<img src="/path/mapped/to/controller/method" />`.

Comment: if you can send image with base64 format; then you can directly include base64 in img src attribute

Comment: like this `<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in angularjs you add function

```
vm.getByte = function(){
  $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/images/{id}/{login}'
  }).success(function(success){
      vm.imgFile = success;
  });
};
```

to get byte array

and in html

```
<img ng-src="data:image/JPEG;base64,{{vm.imgFile}}" style="width: 200px;height: 130px;" />
```